# How to bind selected option value for more than one drop down?

Tags: angular

I have one dynamic array eg: says it's length is 3, After selecting the value in drop down displays three more drop downs. Next after selecting the value in each drop down, Each time image should be displayed. Can anyone please let me know how to display image for each value selected if we have more than drop down.

```
<div *ngFor="let optionValue of number_axles_array">
    Axle {{optionValue}}
    <div>
        Axle type:<br> 
        <select [(ngModel)]="optionValue" (change)="onChangeAxle($event.target.value)">
            <option *ngFor="let taxel of type_axles_array" [ngValue]="taxel.id">{ taxel.type }}</option>
        </select>
        <div (ngModel)="optionValue"*ngIf="multipleSelect">
            <img src="assets/imagename/name.png">    
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Image should be displayed for each of the value in drop down if we have more than one drop down.

Comment: Prepare stackblitz. https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: Please find the problem scenario : - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-spt5re?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts .    Image should be displayed for each drop down change, but its outputting for all drop down at first click. Please help me out on this.

Comment: As for starters, you cannot use the same model field for every `select` unless that isintentional.

Comment: It is requirement that we received from the client , number_axles_array is dynamic array selected by user eg: say 3. Next three drop downs of same model field should be displayed. Images should be displayed on the customer selected value for each drop down.

Comment: But having array does not mean that you will bind to the same field. You have to bind to array and this is not how it is done. Every select must be bound to separate array element.

Comment: Requirement is designed in such a way !!!! , I could have attached picture of requirement but am not able to attach it here.

Comment: *Requirement is designed in such a way.* So changing 1 selection should change every other selections as well to the same value? If so, than it is fine. If not than you have problem.

Comment: Images pops when I do first selection. Is that intentional? You want images to be shown one by one after selecting each selection??

Comment: Yes, I want to show one by one after selecting each selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest I must only assume what you want to do as your description is unclear to me. The assumption here is that you want to display image after selection on every select box. Working example is here

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3hxg2n?file=src/app/app.component.html

And what I did

Template

```
<div *ngFor="let selection of selections">
  Axle {{selection.value}}
  <div >
    Axle type:<br> <select [(ngModel)]="selection.value" (change)="onChangeAxle($event.target.value)">
      <option *ngFor="let taxel of ['drive','steer']">
        {{ taxel }}        
      </option>
    </select>
    <div (ngModel)="optionValue" *ngIf="multipleSelect && selection.value">
     <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQS-I2Dee6yl3TqOv7DIeKB0jqHx1gu9xGv4BpSPoDuuvb0ZFQ7">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Component

```
selections = [];
  ngOnInit() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      this.selections.push({
        idx:i,
        value:""
      })
    }
  }
```

Results in

[image]

Comment: @VasukiHebbar Consider upvoting and accepting answer since it solves the issue.